# Describing the solution to a nonlinear PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

Given the pde $$xu_x+yu_y+uu_z=0$$ where $$u(x,y,0)=xy$$ for $x>0$ and $y>0$, the solution, gotten from the method of characteristics is $$u(x,y,z) = xye^{\frac{-2x}{u}}$$

My question is, how would one describe this solution? I have no idea how to even imagine it.

Thanks.

EDIT: Workings

Characteristics : $$\frac{dx}{x} = \frac{dy}{y} = \frac{dz}{u} = \frac{du}{0}$$

$\frac{du}{dx} = 0 \implies u = K_1 = $ constant

$\frac{dx}{dy} = \frac{x}{y} \implies \frac{y}{x} = K_2$

$\frac{dy}{dz} = \frac{y}{u} = \frac{y}{K_1} \implies \ln (y) - \frac{z}{u} = K_3$

So, $u = F(K_2, K_3) = F(\frac{y}{x},\ln (y) -\frac{z}{u}) = F(X,Y)$

Using the initial condition give above, $xy = F(\frac{y}{x},\ln(y))$. So, $X = \frac{y}{x}$ and $Y = \ln (y)$. Solving for $x$ and $y$, we get that $xy = \frac{e^{2Y}}{X}$

Then, $u(x,y,z) = \frac{e^{2Y}}{x} = \frac{xe^{2(\ln(y)-z/u)}}{y} = xye^{\frac{-2z}{u}}$

Comment: Please show your working for how you got $xye^{\frac{-2x}{u}}$ - I am wondering why there is a $u$ there.

Comment: Edited the above to include the workings.

Comment: If your solution is correct, you should use an substitution to express the function by the Lambert W function.

Comment: What you have shown is that $u(x=x_0e^s,y=y_0e^s,z=x_0y_0s) = x_0 y_0$. This can be expressed as $u(x,y,z) = xy e^{-2 g^{-1}(xy/z)}$ where $g^{-1}$ is the inverse function of $g(s) = e^{2s}/s$.

Answer (score 0):

It's an inavoidably implicit function. Some nice way to visualize some of its characteristics is using a 3D plotter. For a three variables function the surfaces of $u$ constant are interesting to see. It's easy to isolate $z$ as function of $x$, $y$, and $u=k$. I've used [GeoGebra to plot these surfaces](https://ggbm.at/jBRDFx9t). It has an slider to change the value of $k$

$$k=xy^{-2z/k}\implies z=-(k/2)\ln(k/xy)$$

[image]

Isolating $z$ has problems as function, so, you can isolate $x$ and change variables $\bar x=z$, $\bar z=x$ and $\bar y=y$ for the program could plot the function (entered always as $z=f=f(x,y)$

Comment: But what about if I was to describe it as sets of points in $\mathbb{R}^4$ with respect to restrictions on the function? Any idea on how I'd do that? Thanks for your answer.